# Why does one example give an error in while the other does not

Tags: c

The following code does not give an error in C

```
char * p;
 if (p && *p) then 
foo();
```

However, the following does:

```
char * p;
 if (*p && p) then 
foo();
```

Does this have to do with dereferencing the pointer before calling the regular expression in the second example? If so, could someone explain why?

Edit: Sorry for the confusion but this was an example in my programming class so I believe that the instructor took the liberty of putting `then` to highlight that an error would show. I took the code directly from the lecture slide so I believe that the focus was more on the following `(p && *p)` rather than what followed

Comment: There is no `then` keyword in C, could you post the actual code?

Comment: What does "give an error" mean? A compiler message? A crash? Not working as expected? (What did you expect?) And what's "calling a regular expression"? And pseudo-code isn't really helpful for questions like these...

Comment: well, it's not `does not`, `may not` is properer. it's not that possible for `p` to be initialized to `NULL` so the dereferencing would hardly happen in 1st example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code samples are obviously invalid C. As others have already pointed out, C has no `then` keyword. That was probably just an error by your instructor, not intended to illustrate anything in particular. I'll show similar examples that illustrate the point.

This code is correct:

```
char *p;
/* code that assigns a value to p omitted */
if (p && *p)
    foo();
```

Any scalar value can be used as a condition; if it's equal to zero it's treated as false, otherwise as true. (In the original sample, `p` was uninitialized, causing undefined behavior if its value is used, but I'll assume any initialization code was simply omitted.)

The above can be written more explicitly as:

```
char *p;
/* code that assigns a value to p omitted */
if (p != NULL && *p != '\0')
    foo();
```

Evaluating `*p` would be invalid (causing undefined behavior) if `p` were a null pointer. By testing whether `p` is null before trying to dereference it, the above code avoids any such error, since `&&` has short-circuit behavior. The `if` statement could also be written as:

```
if (p != NULL) {
    if (*p != '\0') {
        foo();
    }
}
```

The code calls the function `foo` if `p` is a non-null pointer that points to a non-null character. (These are two different meanings of the word "null".) If `p` is meant to be a pointer to a string, then `p != '\0'` means that the string it points to is not empty.

Now to the second example:

```
char *p;
/* code that assigns a value to p omitted */
if (*p && p)
    foo();
```

or, more explicitly:

```
char *p;
/* code that assigns a value to p omitted */
if (*p != '\0' && p != NULL)
    foo();
```

This causes undefined behavior (possibly a program crash) if `p` is a null pointer. The check `p != NULL` is performed too late, after the program has already crashed.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does one example give an error in while the other does not?

This is because both of the code snippet invokes undefined behavior. You should note that, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes UB.

**NOTE:** There is no `then` keyword in C.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the first sample may or may not cause dereferencing. But it is UB anyway.